# Is it mandatory to define the java plugin to download the depdendency in gradle script?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am writing the gradle script where I need to download the multiple jar files from artifactory I am using the apply plugin 'java' in gradle script and able to fetch those jar files from artifactory easily but if I apply this plugin it run the jar task automatically and creates the jar which I don't want.Is there a way to download the jar files from artifactory with/without using the java plugin so that jar task couldn't trigger.

```
apply plugin 'java'
apply plugin: 'base'

//-- set the group for publishing
group = 'com.abcdef.covery'

/**
 * Initializing GAVC settings
 */
def buildProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withInputStream { 
    stream -> buildProperties.load(stream) 
} 
//add the jenkins build version to the version
def env = System.getenv()
if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) buildProperties.coveryadBuildVersion += "_${env["BUILD_NUMBER"]}"
version = buildProperties.scoveryadBuildVersion
println "${version}"

//name is set in the settings.gradle file
group = "com.abcdef.discovery"
version = buildProperties.coveryadBuildVersion
println "Building ${project.group}:${project.name}"


  repositories {
    maven {
      url "http://art.tsh.tho.com:90000/artifactory/services"
    }
  }

dependencies {
    runtime "covery.services:AddService:1.0@jar"    
    runtime "covery.services:AddService:1.1@jar"
   runtime "covery.services:Services:1.0@jar"
    runtime "covery.services:Services:1.1@jar"
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
from configurations.runtime
into 'services/discovery/services/'
}
```

output:Below shows few tasks which are running while using the java plugin in the script and if I don't use then it doesn't download the jar files from artifactory.

16:28:32 Building com.abcdefgh.discovery:cdad
16:28:33 [buildinfo] Properties file found at 'C:\Windows\TEMP\buildInfo429617857022686528.properties'
16:28:35 :copyDeps UP-TO-DATE
16:28:36 :deletebuild
16:28:37 :buildreportZip
16:28:38 :deleteGraphicsAssets
16:28:47 :unzip
16:28:47 :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
16:28:47 :processResources UP-TO-DATE
16:28:47 :classes UP-TO-DATE
16:28:47 :jar
16:28:47 :artifactoryPublish
16:28:47 Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/abcdefg/covery/cdad/03_00_00_183/cdad-03_00_00_183.zip
16:28:53 Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/abcdefl/covery/cdad/03_00_00_183/cdad-03_00_00_183.jar

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add the java plugin to download dependencies. If you do not have any java source files I would recommend that you use the baseplugin instead:

```
apply plugin: 'base'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    nameOfMyConfiguration
}

dependencies {
    nameOfMyConfiguration 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4'
}

task zipMyStuff(type: Zip) {
    from configurations.nameOfMyConfiguration
}
```